# Django Many to Many - how do you apply a filter on relation

Tags: django, python-3.x, many-to-many

How do you apply a filter to a many to many relation, such that the return of the parent record contains filtered results on the many to many relation.

```py
# model.py
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

Insert into db

```
>>> p1 = Publication(title='P1')
>>> p1.save()
>>> p2 = Publication(title='P2')
>>> p2.save()
>>> p3 = Publication(title='P3')
>>> p3.save()
>>> a1 = Article(headline='A1')
>>> a1.save()
>>> a1.publications.add(p1, p2)
>>> a2 = Article(headline='A2')
>>> a2.save()
>>> a2.publications.add(p1, p2)
```

Forward Output

```
>>> query_set = Article.objects.filter(publications__title='P1')
>>> article1 = query_set.first()
>>> article1
>>> <Article: Article object(1)>
>>> article1.publications.all()
>>> <QuerySet [<Publication: Publication object (1)>, <Publication: Publication object (2)>]>
```

Reverse Output

```
>>> query_set = Publication.objects.filter(article__headline='A1', title='P1')
>>> publication1 = query_set.first()
>>> publication1
>>> <Publication: Publication object(1)>
>>> publication1.article.all()
>>> <QuerySet [<Article: Article object (1)>, <Article: Article object (2)>]>
```

## Expectation

On the forward lookup, I was expecting to get Article-1 with Publication-1.
Instead, it returns Article-1 with Publication-1 & 2.

On the reverse lookup, I was expecting to get Publication-1 with Article-1.
Instead, it returns Publication-1 with Article-1 & 2.

The return type is expected to be `<QuerySet [<Article: Article object (1)>,..]>` and not `<QuerySet [{'headline': 'A1', 'publications': 1},..]>`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: but the second query is the same with first one, you have just added one more column into "select"

Comment: Yes. This is to prove that query returns what is expected, but for the query_set result I don't know what extra steps django is taking which, returns all the Bar objects for a Foo object.